# Highcharts Line Graph Not Working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

I am using a line graph from [Highcharts Demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) and it's not working in IE8 and IE7. Pulling what hair I have left out. I then visited the site and also get the error there. Can anyone please shed some light on the situation?

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Fri, 22 Mar 2013 12:11:16 UTC

Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js

Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js

Message: 'Highcharts' is undefined
Line: 361
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

Message: 'Highcharts' is undefined
Line: 48
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/
```

Comment: This could be a problem of trailing `,` in the highchart code, It seems like that. If you could postthat in your question that will be easier to give you the solution.

Comment: When you say "I visited the site and got the error there", do you mean you went to the demo page? I've just checked the demo page in IE8, and it's fine. A little bit slow, but it works fine. The only possible reason I can think for it to work in one copy of IE8 and not another is if you've got VML disabled (note - VML is an activeX control, so disabling activeX would disable VML).

Comment: Which version of IE8 do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series data doesn't seem to be valid - adjusted as necessary. there was a trailing comma.

Comment: Please take look again in our page, now all should be correct. As I see charts are displayed correct in IE8 and IE7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to internet options

Under Accelerated Graphics
check "use software rendering instead of GPU Rendering"